# keeping track of changing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, tree, multimap

I have a red black tree algorithm which is working fine.  When a node is inserted into the tree, the insert() method returns to the caller a pointer to the node that was inserted.  I store all such pointers in a STL vector.

The problem is, within the operation of the RB tree, sometimes these pointers are invalidated.  For instance, there is a method that is called during a rotateleft/right that copies the values of node A into the current node and then deletes node A.  Well I had a pointer to node A in that vector which is now invalid.

I thought about making a way to update the pointers in the vector as follows,

1) keep a multimap which maps node pointers to the vector indices that holds those pointers.

2) Before deleting a node, check this multimap to find all the spots in the vector that will be affected

3)  iterate over the vector and change the old pointer to the new pointer

4)  Update the key value in the multimap to reflect the new pointer as well.

Problem is, you can't update a key value of a map collection for obvious reasons.  Also this seems like a horrible solution both for complexity and implementation reasons.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this dynamic updating of pointers?

Comment: Can you use pointers to both the next and the previous node? This way, if you change a pointer, you can follow its "prev" pointer and correct the pointer there.

Comment: Your scenario sounds unnecessarily complicated.  Why do you need the vector of pointers to nodes?  If you want the set of all nodes, you can traverse through the tree.

Comment: Agree with Alan. Why keeping pointers in the vector in the first place? Usually, keeping raw pointers at different places is a big trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems more reasonable to keep the data in some opaque data structure pointed by node, and to keep external pointers to this structures instead of nodes.

Basicly it means adding a level of indirection between the tree and actual data.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  Can you flesh this out a bit?  Your phrasing is confusing however, this was more or less what I had in mind.  Some layer of indirection between the two that I can keep consistent with changes.

Comment: @agent0range: what I don't understand is why would you need to save pointers to the nodes? The tree does it anyway.

Comment: I needed to store them all as a requirement.  This was all in implementing an extra credit.  I agree that this wouldn't have been an issue if there weren't a need for a persistent storage AS the items were added.  I ended up making the vector contain the pointers to dynamically allocated data which the nodes were also pointing to.  Works but now I've got some messy heap cleanup... but that's for another thread

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're trying to do, but to keep track of items added to tree/heap data structures, the following has worked for me in the past:

Store two "index" vectors in addition to the underlying tree data:

```
std::vector<int> item_to_tree;
std::vector<int> tree_to_item;
```

So, to find the index in the tree of the ith item, use `item_to_tree[i]`. To find the item at a particular jth tree index, use `tree_to_item[j]`. This is similar to storing explicit pointers, as you've done, but by making use of indices you can essentially get a bi-directional map with O(1) lookup.

Obviously, within the tree operations, you have to make sure that the mappings stay consistent. I've not thought about this for an RB tree, but definitely for other tree-like structures this just adds some O(1) complexity to each operation.

In the case of the ith item "removed" from the tree, `tree_to_item` no longer contains the ith item index, and I usually set item_to_tree[i] = -1, or some "empty" flag.

Hope this helps.